# Best Practices in Lieu of Recurring Payments?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, civipledge

I'm working with an NGO in Indonesia, which currently has roughly 100 regular donors per month, to transition to CiviCRM for its donations and event management. Thus far we have been hampered by a number of factors, including relatively low levels of credit card penetration, complex banking infrastructure, and a relatively underdeveloped e-commerce environment. We have been very fortunate to have found a payment gateway that has been very supportive (www.midtrans.com), and they wrote an extension to integrate their off-site payment option (thus eliminating the need for the NGO's website to be PCI compliant) with the NGO's instance of CiviCRM. That extension is currently available at: https://github.com/rizdaprasetya/vtweb-civicrm (*note, the installation is a little finnicky, but once installed, it works fine). Furthermore, the payment processor's documentation is quite extensive: https://github.com/rizdaprasetya/vtweb-civicrm

The challenge we are currently facing is that the payment processor is unable to process automatic recurring transactions which forces us into a bit of a conundrum. Like many Indonesian NGOs, this group has collected personal info and payment details (ie. credit card numbers) and has up to now been forced to process these transactions manually each month by sending a password-protected Excel file to each issuing bank to request transactions be processed. Obviously this presents some security liabilities, along with being very time/resource intensive.

On the other hand, we could transition all of the current donors over to a self-service, pledge-based system. This would eliminate the burden on the NGO's staff, and would also significantly mitigate and liability from the potential loss of confidential data. However, in doing so, it would shift the burden to the donor, requiring them to click through the pledge reminder email and enter their payment details each month.

Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed in lieu of a recurring payment option in this case? I know it's not ideal, but I'm looking to figure out how to make the best of an imperfect situation. Have others gone through this decision-making process, and how was an optimal solution reached?

Any advice or considerations you might have would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

-Justin